# Single query to get data from 3 separate tables based on provided timestamp

Tags: mysql

I'm working with three tables which can be summarized as follows:

Table1 (**pid**, **created**, data, link1)
Table2 (**pid**, **created**, data)
Table3 (**link1**, **created**, data)

The created field is a UNIX timestamp, and the data field is the same format in each table.

I want to get the data in all 3 tables such that Table1.pid = Table2.pid AND Table1.link1 = Table3.link1 AND created is less than and closest to a given timestamp value.

So, as an example, say I provide a date of May 7, 2011, 1:00pm.  I'd want the data record from each table created most recently before this date-time.

Now I've managed to do this in a rather ugly single query involving sub-queries (using either INNER JOINs **or** UNIONs), but I'm wondering whether it can be done w/o sub-queries in a single query?  Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously I haven't really run the query, but it seems like it would do whatever you need if I'm understanding your question right.

t1.pid and t2.pid are the same, t1.link1 and t3.link1 are the same, and none of the .created are above your time, and you want the row closest to the date.

`SELECT t1.data, t2.data, t3.data FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2, Table3 t3 WHERE t1.pid = t2.pid AND t1.link1 = t3.link1 AND GREATEST(t1.created,t2.created,t3.created) < 'your-formatted-time' ORDER BY GREATEST(t1.created,t2.created,t3.created) DESC;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply John, but it doesn't look like your query would ensure the most recent records from each table are obtained.  The ORDER BY clause orders the results by the greatest date of the 3 tables, not the greatest date in each table.  I need the most recent data from each table (that is older than the provided timestamp).

Comment: Sorry about that, for some reason I read your "Table1.pid = Table2.pid" as "Table1.created = Table2.created".

Comment: `SELECT t1.data, t2.data, t3.data FROM t1, t2, t3 WHERE t1.pid = t2.pid AND t1.link1 = t3.link1 AND GREATEST(t1.created, t2.created, t3.created) <= provided_timestamp ORDER BY t1.created DESC, t2.created DESC, t3.created DESC LIMIT 1`  I suppose multiple order by's should work.  Thanks for feedback John.

Comment: Just to clearify what you're looking for.  You mention needing the most recent data from each table that is older than the timestamp, but also mention needing t1.pid = t2.pid and t1.link1 = t3.link1.  Could you either clarify a bit more what your expected output is, or just show the 'rather ugly single query' you're using?

Comment: If you use the query in your comment, you're going to end up with the 1 result (limit 1) that corresponds to the t1.created date, since that's your first order.  If you do the same 'GREATEST' you'll get 1 row that corresponds to the created that's greatest.  Your additional ORDER statements are really only going to matter if you have multiple t1.created with the same exact time.